# Is there any way to add namespaces to all html tags using ASP?

Tags: javascript, regex, asp-classic

Is there any way to add namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` to all html tags either using ASP function / RegExp / javascript? (this is something like adding a attribute to the html tags)

For Example:

Below is the body of textarea:

```
<p>Welcome to the StackOverFlow site.</p>
<p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Please <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">click here</a> for more info.</p>
```

---

The body contains two html tags, `<p>` & `<a>`.

Here one `<p>` tag already has namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`

Now I need to add namespace to other tags.

I tried a lot to resolve this on ASP page but no luck.

Please help me on this.

Comment: In Classic ASP using VBScript? Mind me to ask, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Is there a requirement to add namespaces to each element in the DOM? You can just add it to <html> and it will do it all.

Comment: @roberkules & @Coding-Freak : Yes it's a requirement that i need to handle before it is inserting on to the component. There is no <html> node on this, since it is only a body content..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses only JavaScript regexes:

```
result = subject.replace(
    /(<\w+)((?:\s+(?!xmlns\b)\w+\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\s>]+))*\s*\/?>)/g,
    '$1 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"$2'
);
```

The regex matches anything that looks like an opening tag (`<abc>`) or self-closing tag (`<xyz />`).  The tag may contain any number of attributes, unless one of those attributes is named "xmlns".  The attribute values may be double-quoted, single-quoted, or not quoted.  If a tag is matched, the "xmlns" attribute will be added immediately after the tag name.

Be aware that there's a lot this solution doesn't handle, like "valueless" attributes (e.g. `nowrap`), or tag- or attribute names qualified with namespaces (e.g. `<abc:xyz>`).  Regexes really don't work very well on HTML (which is a shame, since that's what most people seem to want to use them on).  Any regex-vs-HTML solution has to start with an exhaustive list of simplifying assumptions, like "no `<script>` tags" or "don't worry about CDATA sections or SGML comments".

Comment: First I would like to thank you. This looks cool. I have a question, when I'm testing this LOC I come across through the tables. For tables, this LOC is adding to all the table tags such as `<table><tr><td>...` actually for table `xmlns` should be on table root node i.e., `<table>`. Can't we handle this scenario?

Comment: You can treat tag names the same way I treated the attribute names: explicitly exclude the ones you don't want. Something like this:  `(<(?!tr|td)\w+)`.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: That's perfect Alan. Thanks for your help.
Based on your input, below is the final modification I have implemented:- 

`result = subject.replace(
    /(<(?!tr|td|thead|tbody)\w+)((?:\s+(?!xmlns\b)\w+\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\s>]+))*\s*\/?>)/g,
    '$1 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"$2'
);`

I have transformed this to ASP Function and used it...

Answer (score 1):

This would be very simple in jQuery:

For all elements on the page:

```
$("*").attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
```

For all elements of a bit of code in a textarea (e.g. with an id of 'MyTextArea'):

```
$($("#MyTextArea").text()).attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
```

Comment: Thanks james. When I use `$($("#MyTextArea").text()).attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");` this LOC, still tags are not getting the new attribute "xmlns"

Comment: Is there any thing, I need to consider before writting this LOC? I tried a lot with this input but there is no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Alan inputs, I have build my solution on ASP

```
Function ReplaceAllByExpression(str)
    Dim objRegExp, sHtml
    sHtml = str
    Set objRegExp = New RegExp

    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.Global = True
    objRegExp.MultiLine = True

    objRegExp.Pattern = "(<(?!tr|td|thead|tbody)\w+)((?:\s+(?!xmlns\b)\w+\s*=\s*(?:""[^""]*""|'[^']*'|[^\s>]+))*\s*\/?>)"

    sHtml = objRegExp.Replace(sHtml, "$1 xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml""$2")

    ReplaceAllByExpression = sHtml

End Function
```